# Speed up Xamarin App Start

Tags: c#, android, performance, xamarin

Yo!
My Xamarin App takes now 3 seconds till my breakpoint gets to the first line of code. I want to speed things up if possible or at least make some loading animation or Logo while we wait. 
is this possible?

some infos: my whole code is loaded in the App.xaml.cs, i build my whole user interface there, i just load 2 images as resources (2x200KB) and one font in the android folder. 
Namespaces i use:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using PCLStorage;
using SQLite;
using ModernHttpClient;
using System.Net.Http;
```

it would be nice at least having a little startup animation e.g. an App logo or something like that to cover up the 3s delay but if it takes 3s to reach the code i can't do it in code.

btw: i just tested on android because i don't have an IOS or Windows Phone

---

Maybe it's helpful to post this link to my current source code:
https://pastebin.com/v2hv0ur4
the rest of my project is just the standard Xamarin Project, when opening a new one plus a new font in the android folder and 2x200KB images.
also the other code files are exactly as they were, i do not use XAML.

Comment: are you using xamarin forms or what? did you try googling? [many](https://blog.xamarin.com/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/) guides for that cause it's known that xamarin app startups take a long time...

Comment: Benchmark in Release mode + Linker enabled instead.

Comment: so releasemode is faster but what's benchmark? 
yes i'm using forms, i just looked at google and found something about code optimization and something about not putting too many resources... well i got 3 resources, 2 just because image reading doesn't work in xamarin... so i need to put them in the resources and read them from stream.

Comment: [Refer to this](https://github.com/brminnick/ImproveXamarinBuildTimes) and [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/)

Comment: Well then:
i'm not using XAML i do everything in C#
my layouts are exact the way they are i won't be able to use others
i don't think i have unneccessary binding... though i don't really know what they mean with it. do they mean that instructor stuff () { ... }?
Basically: since the first line of code is delayed 3-5 seconds it can't be a code problem right?

would it be of help if i'd post my total code?